# Windows: command "npm install drizzle" give me an ERR!

Tags: truffle, drizzle, frontend

npm WARN deprecated fs-promise@2.0.3: Use mz or fs-extra^3.0 with Promise Support

npm WARN deprecated tar.gz@1.0.7: ⚠️  WARNING ⚠️ `tar.gz module has been deprecated and your application is vulnerable. Please use tar module instead: https://npmjs.com/tar

npm ERR! path C:\Users\Ricca\Drizzle\app\node_modules\websocket

npm ERR! code EISGIT

npm ERR! git C:\Users\Ricca\Drizzle\app\node_modules\websocket: Appears to be a git repo or submodule.

npm ERR! git     C:\Users\Ricca\Drizzle\app\node_modules\websocket

npm ERR! git Refusing to remove it. Update manually,

npm ERR! git or move it out of the way first.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

npm ERR!     C:\Users\Ricca\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2019-08-06T07_27_49_028Z-debug.log

this is the message what return when i'm trying to run this command.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume you are using windows because I got the same problem:
first I search for the error "npm ERR! code EISGIT".
Solution I found is by using this command `rm -rf node_modules/*/.git/` 
Next, I encountered with another errors related to python. I didn't have python in windows, so I installed python 2.7 and drizzle installed correctly... 
I'm following drizzle docs tutorial, not encountered a problem yet (besides the one in this question) [enter link description here](https://www.trufflesuite.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-drizzle-and-react)